# MinGW does not recognise #pragma GCC optimize

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

I have a header only library that relies on heavy template metaprogramming. In Debug it may provide an object file of an enormous size, that is optimized out in Release mode. I don't want to force the users of my library to take care of this problem manually, thus I need to force optimization for parts of code within my header.

But on Windows MinGW seems to not recognize the `#pragma GCC optimize ("Os")`.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("Os")
#endif
```

Even with these pragmas Debug linking fails with

```
C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUYGDJ.s: Fatal error: can't close Modules/Devices/EuroFlir410/external/CMakeFiles/test.Euroflir410.conversion.dir/test_conversion.cpp.obj: file too big
```

Thus it does nothing...

How can I circumvent this problem?

---

MinGW does not recognize `#pragma GCC target` either

Comment: ¿How much is "enormous"? ¿Have you considered that forcing users to deal with mixed optimization translation units using non-standard extension creates bigger problem?

Comment: Please read [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html).

Comment: @user7860670 in my case it is so big that linker rejects it with "file too big" message. In Release everything is fine

Comment: ¿And how big is "too big" (in numbers)? Perhaps it is worth investigating. This question seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: If you have such complex templates so that it expands to such large amount of code that the linker refuses to handle it, then maybe it's just too complex? It sounds like it's going to be a maintenance nightmare. Also, temporarily enabling optimizations for this header file only seems like a stop-gap solution and might not work in the long term.

Comment: @user7860670 does it *really* matter? When I find a library on github, I expect just to plug it in and use without tweaking my machine. One of colleagues says that on his machine memory consumtion rises up to 11 Gb when compiling Debug. So the simple guess is to force debug on template code that will never be used at runtime anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I absolutely agree with you. But it is up to further investigation and finding out the ways to reduce complexity. For now it solves a really big problem of code maintenance which otherwise can be solved only with preprocessor tools.

Comment: Why do you think GCC should recognise `#pragma GCC optimize push`? Is it documented somewhere? Perhaps you want `#pragma GCC push_options` instead.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it is a wild guess based upon the similar case: `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` works.

Comment: I like wild guesses as much as the next guy, but in the end of the day the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) wins.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude MinGW does not recognize any of the pragmas that are mentioned in the GCC documentation

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I've updated the question. MinGW does not recognize any of those pragmas at *documentation*

Comment: What gcc version does your installation of mingw provide?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.`gcc version 10.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)`

Comment: Please show diagnostic messages resulting from **documented** pragmas. `#pragma GCC optimize push` isn't one.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.you were right. I don't get warnings without "optimize push". However these pragmas still do nothing. I guess I'll update the question

Comment: This is probably because these pragmas only affect functions (just a wild guess).